# Conjunctions and ambiguity

Tags: ambiguity

> Water froze but didn’t melt.

It can mean:

1. Water froze but the water (liquid) didn’t melt. (Water doesn’t melt because it’s already liquid)
2. Water froze but the frozen water (ice) didn’t melt. (Maybe the melting point of the ice is high because it’s mixed with anti-melting material)

Can the other coordinating conjunctions (For, and, nor, but, or, yet) between verbs also be ambiguous like this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community How more can I clarify?

Comment: Your original sentence is more of a sentence fragment. It is not surprising that it is ambiguous. Try making a longer sentence that has the same issue.

Comment: Your sentence is of the form [subject + action] but [same implied subject + contrary outcome], which is perfectly fine. **The real problem isn't the coordinating conjunction, or even ambiguity:** it's that the first subject (liquid water, able to freeze) is NOT same implied second subject (frozen water (ice], able to melt). Put simply: by definition, water can't melt. Are you trying to say that once the water froze, it couldn't melt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Grammatically, there is no ambiguity in this sentence. "Water" is the subject of two predicates: "froze" and "didn’t melt." The same water is performing (or not performing, in the second case) both actions.

I don't think that there is an ambiguity semantically, either. It's been a while since I've studied physics, but if I recall correctly, water can only melt after it has frozen. Therefore, your first numbered sentence is really saying the same thing as your second numbered sentence.

Please add a comment if I've misunderstood what you're trying to say.

Comment: I mean sentence 1 is talking about water but sentence 2 is talking about frozen water because previously I said that water froze.

Comment: If sentence #2 is talking about frozen water (i.e., ice), then it can't be an interpretation of the original sentence, because ice can't freeze. To freeze means to change from liquid to solid, unless there is some meaning that I'm not aware of. (In that case, the issue would be with different meanings of "freeze".)

Comment: No no I mean water froze but (the frozen water) didn’t melt the first verb is talking about water but the second verb is talking about ice because I said water froze.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. So sentence #1: "Water froze but while it was liquid didn’t melt." Sentence #2: "Water froze but while it was solid didn’t melt." Is that right?

Comment: Oh yes that’s what I mean

Comment: Then yes, I guess that either of those things could be interpreted from the original sentence. However, #1 seems pretty pointless; why would anyone say that liquid water didn't melt? I understand that you are asking about ambiguity in general, though; yes, many sentences with coordinating conjunctions can be ambiguous. I can't come up with any examples right now, though; I think that my brain is about to melt! :)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: For me the terms freeze, melt, boil and condense only refer to the phase of matter which can undergo the phase change in that direction. This means that ice can melt, steam or vapour can condense and water can both freeze and boil. However water can't melt or condense, ice can't freeze and vapour can't boil. Under the right conditions vapour can freeze by sublimation but I'm not sure that ice can sublimate to steam under any conditions.